# php mysql multiple table with different columns search approach

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a search on website, I am having total 10 tables that should be searched.

I don't want to use multiple queries like this:

```
SELECT `manufacturer` FROM `auto` WHERE ....
SELECT `city`,`address` FROM `estate` WHERE ....
SELECT `title`,`content` FROM `news` WHERE ....
... and 6 more queries
```

Instead, I want to use a single query to get all the desired data and assign results website URLs to go to.

How should I behave?

Comment: could you please tell us by which columns are you going to search? give us more detailed example of your queries

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to `UNION` your queries

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (
        SELECT `manufacturer` AS sval FROM `auto` WHERE ....
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT CONCAT(`city`,`address`) AS sval FROM `estate` WHERE ....
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT CONCAT(`title`,`content`) AS sval FROM `news` WHERE ....
    )
)
```

Comment: That is just an example, you can even concatenate column value if there are multiple columns that need to be searched through, updated.

Answer (score 0):

Usage separates query is good solution. If you will use all tables in one query then all tables will locked for time of query. And if you will use LIKE or full text search then you ill have lock for your sites.

You can use separates query for each table. Or you can outside index for search. For example you can use sphinx - for build index and search by index.

Comment: I'm not going use sphinx, server won't support such libs. But I have another point. Is not it a bad idea to use separate queries? Which table should I query first then? I mean order, why search news table first if there are better matches in articles.